# Convert Cordova Image Picker Results To Base64 Format Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Problem: I was trying to **convert the image picker result** to **base64** format as it gives result in image uri and don't want to camera plugin as requirement is to select **multiple images from gallery**.

Most of questions have asked about this related issue but nothing help me, here are the already asked question i have gone through
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221459/how-to-convert-cordova-image-picker-results-to-base64-format) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491623/upload-image-ionic-3)

**Here what i have tried to convert image to base64**

```
getImageFromGallery() {

    let options = {
        maximumImagesCount: 3,
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        quality: 50,
        outputType: 0//image uri 
    };

    this.imagepicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.imageurlfrompicker = results[i];

            let resizeoptions = {
                uri: results[i],
                quality: 50,
                width: 800,
                height: 800
            } as ImageResizerOptions;
            this.imageResizer
                .resize(resizeoptions)
                .then((filePath: string) => {

                    this.imageurlfromresizer = filePath;

                    this.convertToBase64(filePath, 'image/png').then(
                        data => {
                            this.imagebase64 = data.toString(); //base64 of image
                            console.log(data.toString());
                            //this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; // old one
                            this.imagelist.push(this.imagebase64);
                            this.imagelist.reverse();


                        }
                    );
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
    }, (err) => { });
}
```

**Code To convert into base64**

```
convertToBase64(url, outputFormat) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
        img.onload = function () {
            let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement('CANVAS'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                dataURL;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            canvas.width = img.width;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
            canvas = null;
            resolve(dataURL);
        };
        img.src = url;
    });
}
```

Please Help to resolve this issue

[Official Link Of Ionic Image Picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/)

Comment: why not use outputType:1 ?

Comment: Hi @SurajRao  i have tried it with output 1, but it doesn't work with image picker as ionic official docs doesn't mentioned about this issue

Comment: it says the plugin provides data uri for outputType 1.https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker#options

Comment: Yes i have tried via setting outputType 1 but return nothing that's why i have posted this question

Comment: I think this plugin help you https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/

Comment: Hi @PareshGami , This plugin need file path, Do you have any idea about converting the image uri(return by image picker) to file path ?

Comment: That plugin helps you to convert in base64 Try it first

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5 canvas API for that may hope it will help you this time

```
  function encodeImageUri(imageUri)
{
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
   var img=new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
     c.width=this.width;
     c.height=this.height;
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    };
   img.src=imageUri;
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    return dataURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin definitely will help **https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/**

I used it to in my project to covert data from imagepicker (both gallery and camera) to base64 string.
IT takes URI to parameters and return promise with base64. I have similar example in my app:

```
saveUserImageFromGallery(): any {
            return this.imagePicker.getPictures(this.imagePickerOptions)
                .then((results) => {
                    return this.resizeAndSave(results[0]);
                }, () => {
                    console.log('Error picking image');
                });
    }
```

**using Base64 plugin**

```
    resizeAndSave(imageUri) {
            return this.cropService.crop(imageUri).then((croppedUri) => {
                    return this.imageResizer
                        .resize({
                            folderName: 'image',
                            uri: croppedUri,
                            quality: 75,
                            width: 300,
                            height: 300,
                            fileName: Date.now() + '.jpg'
                        })
                        .then((filePath: string) => {
                            return this.base64.encodeFile(filePath)
                                .then(base64File => {
                                    console.log('here is base64 string: ', base64File)
                                    return base64File;
                                })
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            console.log('Error resizing image');
                        });
                },
                () => {
                     console.log('Error cropping image');
                })
        }
```

**using File plugin**

```
resizeAndSave(imageUri) {
      return this.cropService.crop(imageUri).then((croppedUri) => {
            return this.imageResizer
                .resize({
                    folderName: 'image',
                    uri: croppedUri,
                    quality: 75,
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    fileName: Date.now() + '.jpg'
                })
                .then((filePath: string) => {
                    let fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
                    let path = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    return this.file.readAsDataURL(path, fileName)
                        .then(base64File => {
                            this.sendUserImage(base64File).subscribe(() => {
                                    console.log("Image saved");
                                },
                                (err) => {
                                    console.log('Error saving image');
                                });
                            return base64File;
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            console.log('Error reading file from');
                        })
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    console.log('Error resizing image');
                });
        },
        () => {
            console.log('Error cropping image');
        })
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine when using with ImageResizer but i want user to select multiple images from gallery and don't want to show the image resizer  to user. Do you have any idea about it

Comment: This tutorial should help you: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-2-image-handling

Just change reduceImages() function and resize image (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-resizer/) without cropping by user. I hope this will help.

Comment: Hi @SurajBahadur 
I checked this Base64 Ionic Native plugin and it suddenly stopped working (it's still beta version). I made some changes in my code and used **File Plugin** instead. Check out my updated code above.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, Thank you , i have used the reference of https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-2-image-handling and it is working and  update your code for multiple images so that i can accept your answer.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, Do you have any idea about multiple images selection without showing cropping to user  ?

Comment: @SurajBahadur this is actually even easier. You can use the latest version of cordova image picker (v. 2.1.8) with ionic native image picker.


`options = {
    maximumImagesCount: 5, // max images
    width: 400, // max width and height in pixels
    height: 400,
    quality: 95
    outputType: 1 // 1 for base64 string, 0 for image uri 
};`


and then use:


`imagePicker.getPictures(
     function(results) {
         for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
         }
     }, function (err) {}
 , options);`

Comment: I have tried by setting outputType:1 but it doesn't return base 64 code. Here is output : "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4ADA64BB-E7A5-4723-BB8C-A4A3E7ED1B00/tmp/cdv_photo_006.jpg"  .

Comment: Make sure that yo're using updated version of plugin "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "2.1.8" and "@ionic-native/image-picker": "4.5.3".
It's working fine in my project.